# Adding magento themes without connect

Tags: magento-connect

I am new to magento.i don't know how to install magento theme.what are the different types of methods.

Answer (score 2):

Just FTP the theme files to the root[image: You should have some/all of these folders]

You should have some/all of these folders. Then you just need to refrence the theme name in the Config section of your admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

There two folders in Magento that dictate how your pages look on the frontend:

`{MAGNETO_ROOT}/app/design/frontend/base/`

or `{MAGNETO_ROOT}/app/design/frontend/enterprise/` if you are running Magento Enterprise.

Folders/files here dictate the layout structure and content of your pages.

and

`{MAGNETO_ROOT}/skin/frontend/base/`

or `{MAGNETO_ROOT}/skin/frontend/enterprise/` again, if you are running and Enterprise version.

Folders/files here contain the images, css styling, and javascript libraries used by your pages.

Look at the path of the theme you are trying to add, if the folder contains `layout` or `template` folders then it would go here:

`{MAGNETO_ROOT}/app/design/frontend/base/{NEW_THEME}/`

If the path of your new theme contains `css`, `js`, or `images` folders then you would add it here:

`{MAGNETO_ROOT}/skin/frontend/base/{NEW_THEME}/`

Your new theme can contain both, so you would have to add those folders accordingly.

To enable your new theme go to the admin panel under `System -> Configuration -> Design` you will see a collapsed group called `Themes`. In here, type in your theme folder name for each folder you added.

For example if I only added a `skin` to my `{MAGNETO_ROOT}/skin/frontend/base/{NEW_THEME}/` then I would set `Skin (Images / CSS): {NEW_THEME}`

If added a `design` folder to `{MAGNETO_ROOT}/app/design/frontend/base/{NEW_THEME}/` and that folder contained either a `layout` or a `templates` folders OR both. I would add `Layout: {NEW_THEME}` and/or `Templates: {NEW_THEME}`

`{NEW_THEME}` can be any name you give your folder, i.e. helloWorld, just make sure you type that same name in the admin panel `System -> Configuration -> Design`. Hope that helps!